# Why does the <a> tag represent links, when a perfectly valid <link> tag exists?

Tags: conventions

There's probably a historical reason for this, but I don't know where to start looking for where this might be documented.

Specifically, instead of the cryptic "anchor tag" with a "hypertext reference" (well, I suppose terminology was different back then):

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>
```

why didn't something like this happen?

```
<link to="https://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</link>
```

What exactly did "anchor" mean anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [W3 docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.1):

> A link has two ends -- called anchors -- and a direction. The link starts at the "source" anchor and points to the "destination" anchor, which may be any Web resource (e.g., an image, a video clip, a sound bite, a program, an HTML document, an element within an HTML document, etc.).

I'm not an expert in the field, but I believe that it is merely because of the terminology at the time. Reading that article can provide more details about the definitions, but you may need to message the original authors or historians to provide a creditable answer.

Comment: Well, I'll be damned, there is an actual reason.

Comment: @cchan3141 Uhhh, yes it is. I'll fix my answer. Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

`A` was short for anchor, which could be a url or a named anchor (created with `<a name="myanchor">text</a>`).  The `text` in my example would not be visually different, and another `A` tag could set its `href` to #myanchor.  When clicked, the browser would scroll the named A tag to the top of the page, or at least ensure it was visible.

Link wasn't added until later, and it means something else semantically.

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

As to why, I think only the Html group at the time could answer, but i'd guess that since you could link to another page or within the document, hyper linking wasn't all it could do.  Or perhaps since bandwidth was more expensive, brevity had a higher value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've clarified the question.

Comment: @cchan3141 I added more, does that answer your question?

Comment: Yup! Thanks. I'll see if someone from the HTML working group at the time comes along, but otherwise yours is the accepted answer. :)

Comment: @cchan3141 Might consider this answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38448273/347348  Whatever you pick, be sure to actually accept the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to the one you want.

Answer (score 2):

The link tag references a link the current document has with an external source, so it is used to specify a link with associated CSS files. Your thinking is "hyperlink", which is different to the tag's intended usage.
As for your new question about "anchor", I would assume it got its name as an anchor is stuck to its place, and the anchor tag points to a specific location (sometimes on the same page, using #id).